# Command to write all .js files to a single file?

Tags: command-line, files, grep

I am trying to put all `.js` files in a directory and sub directories into a single file in lexical order. I have tried:

```
grep -r --include=*.js * > dir/.filename
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to find all files ending with `.js` extension recursively?

Comment: @heemayl yes I am trying to combine all files ending in .js in lexical order.  The recursive part is to included sub dirs.

Comment: If you want to build system automating tasks, I think [gulp]http://gulpjs.com/ is a good tool.  `gulp-concat` concatenates all files, then minify or something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `find` to find the files and then `sort` to sort the names:

```
find . -type f -name '*.js' | sort
```

To save the names in a file:

```
find . -type f -name '*.js' | sort >files.txt
```

Let's analyze your command:

```
grep -r --include=*.js *
```

- You need to put a directory name as argument while using `-r` option e.g. (also put `''` around glob match so that they don't produce unexpected results):

  ```
  grep -r --include='*.js' .
  ```

  This would look for non-empty files i.e. this is equivalent to:

  ```
  grep -r --include='*.js' '.' .
  ```
- If you want to check for a specific pattern e.g. lines starting with `TERM`:

  ```
  grep -r --include='*.js' '^TERM' .
  ```

Anyway the main point is `grep` is searching the file contents for any match but your goal is to match against the file names so you should go for something else that can do that e.g. `find` or a shell loop.

---

You can also use the `globstar` option of `bash` to search for files ending in `.js` recursively and then sort them using `sort`.

At first you need to enable the `globstar` option of `bash`:

```
shopt -s globstar
```

Now `**/*.js` will find the files (and directories) with `.js` extension.

So the following should do the trick:

```
for i in **/*.js; do [[ -f $i ]] && echo "$i"; done
```

`[[ -f $i ]]` is there to ensure that we are dealing with only files on output.

Answer (score 0):

`grep` is a line matching tool. It is suitable for *searching contents* of a file, but not searching files themselves.

Use `find` command to do that. Find is recursive by default and has many many options for optimizing search.

For instance, if I wanted to recursively find all of the regular files (not directories) with extension `*.png` recursively from `/home` directory and down to the subdirectories, I would tell `find` to start from `/home` directory, search for files with `-type`, and use case-insensetive matching with `-iname` for files that end in ".png".

```
xieerqi:$ find /home -type f -iname "*.png" | head
/home/xieerqi/Downloads/35457542.png
/home/xieerqi/genymotion/icons/icon.png
/home/xieerqi/chinese-calendar-0.8.2/skin/default/ok.png
/home/xieerqi/chinese-calendar-0.8.2/skin/default/no.png
/home/xieerqi/chinese-calendar-0.8.2/skin/default/note.png
/home/xieerqi/chinese-calendar-0.8.2/skin/default/chinesecalendarBGyellow.png
/home/xieerqi/chinese-calendar-0.8.2/skin/blue/ok.png
/home/xieerqi/chinese-calendar-0.8.2/skin/blue/no.png
/home/xieerqi/chinese-calendar-0.8.2/skin/blue/note.png
/home/xieerqi/chinese-calendar-0.8.2/skin/blue/chinesecalendarBGblue.png
```